# add a string in regex pattern

Tags: perl, awk, sed

any idea to insert a substring (`;[^;]*` in this case) into a regex pattern that is `;` separated in a specific place (add a 4th field in my case where there is ALWAYS 4 field). 
Problem is that value in "field" are regex and the char `;` could exist  as pattern (like in class or escaped char) and not separator.

It's on a AIX so no GNU tools available (posix sed or awk).

sample of possible string and expected result

```
lazy;dog;are;running
-> lazy;dog;are;[^;]*;running

[^;]*;dog;are;[^;]*
-> [^;]*;dog;are;[^;]*;[^;]*

[^,;:0-9]*;dog;are;\;running
-> [^,;:0-9]*;dog;are;[^;]*;\;running
```

i try a  `sed 's/;[^;]*$/[^;]*;&/'` based on first string but cannot build the modification on sed for other special case due to lack of back reference value
(i think a perl or maybe an awk to avoid a heavy batch/sed

Comment: so you don't want to calculate the semicolon which was present inside the `[]` ?

Comment: right, nor `;` in `\;` for same reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Perl.

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\\);((?:\[[^\]]*\]|\\;|[^;])+)$/;[^;]*;\1/g' file
lazy;dog;are;[^;]*;running
[^;]*;dog;are;[^;]*;[^;]*
[^,;:0-9]*;dog;are;[^;]*;\;running
```

[REGEX Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/214)

Comment: seems perfect :-) perl can use back reference. Thks